# Google Sheets App Script Custom Function Re-executing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

[![

```js
function TEST_APP(ticker, token) {

  return [ticker+ticker]
}
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb64H.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb64H.png)I have a custom function in Apps Script that is calling an external TD Ameritrade API.  My understanding is that custom functions do not re-execute unless its input parameters change.  However my custom function keeps executing every so often, sometimes every 10 mins sometimes every 60 mins or so without the input parameters changing.

How do I fix this?

I have created a token to send the custom function to have it invoke only when I change the input to refresh the data.  However the function is executing on its own.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Custom functions get re-evaluated from time to time, for example every time you open the spreadsheet.

To execute the custom function less often, try invoking it like this:

```
=lambda( 
  ticker, token, 
  TEST_APP(ticker, token) 
)(A1, A2)
```

Alternatively, use the [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache), like this:

```js
function TEST_APP(ticker, token) {
  const cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  const cacheKey = [ticker, token].join('→');
  const cached = cache.get(cacheKey);
  if (cached) {
    return JSON.parse(cached);
  }
  const result = ticker + ticker;
  cache.put(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(result), 6 * 60 * 60); // 6 hours
  return result;
}
```